# Can not get value from ModelMap in JSP page

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i try to use ModelMap in my project, but i cannot access ModelMap value in JSP page.

my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter">
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, 
        but for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, 
        so we must define an explicit mapping for it. -->
    <bean id="urlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.html">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- The index controller. -->
    <bean name="indexController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
        p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

my tiles.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="index" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/index.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="dangkyphong" template="WEB-INF/jsp/partical/main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="WEB-INF/jsp/partical/dangkyphong.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="quanlyphong" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/quanlyphong.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="quanlymaytinh" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/quanlymaytinh.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="themphong" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/themphong.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="themay" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/themmay.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="chinhsuapc" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/chinhsuapc.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

my project free

[image: my project free]

i try this:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap mm) {
        mm.put("title", "Home");
        return "index";
    }
```

in JSP page i try use: `${title}`

but i cannot get a string "Home" in JSP title

please help me solve this issue !
----edit My JSP page----

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>${title}</title>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name = "head" ignore="true"></tiles:insertAttribute>
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/custom.css" type="text/css" />
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidedrawer" class="navbar-default mui--no-user-select"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.html">
                <div id="sidedrawer-brand" class="mui--appbar-line-height mui--text-title">Labs Manager</div></a>
            <div class="mui-divider"></div>
            <ul>     
                <strong>Quản Lý Phòng Máy</strong>
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav-menu">
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index/themphong.html">
                            <span class="small-nav" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Home"> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
                            </span>
                            <span class="full-nav"> Thêm Phòng </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-menu">
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index/dangkyphong.html">
                            <span class="small-nav" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="About Us"> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> 
                            </span>
                            <span class="full-nav"> Đăng Ký Phòng </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-menu">
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index/quanlyphong.html">
                            <span class="small-nav" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Contact Us"> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> 
                            </span>
                            <span class="full-nav"> Quản Lý Phòng </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <strong>Quản Lý Máy Tính</strong>
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav-menu">
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index/themmay.html">
                            <span class="small-nav" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Contact Us"> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
                            </span>
                            <span class="full-nav"> Thêm Máy</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-menu">
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index/chinhsuapc.html">
                            <span class="small-nav" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Contact Us"> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> 
                            </span>
                            <span class="full-nav"> Chỉnh Sửa </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="mui-appbar mui--appbar-line-height">
                <div class="mui-container-fluid">
                    <a class="sidedrawer-toggle mui--visible-xs-inline-block mui--visible-sm-inline-block js-show-sidedrawer">☰</a>
                    <a class="sidedrawer-toggle mui--hidden-xs mui--hidden-sm js-hide-sidedrawer">☰</a>
                    <span class="mui--text-title mui--visible-xs-inline-block mui--visible-sm-inline-block">Labs Manager</span>

                    <ul  class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li id="user-nav" class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hello, Administrator<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>


            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div class="mui--appbar-height"></div>
            <div class="mui-container-fluid">
                <!-- Main Content -->

                <tiles:insertAttribute name="content"></tiles:insertAttribute>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer id="footer">
                <div class="mui-container-fluid">
                    <br>
                    Copyright &COPY; 2016
                </div>
            </footer>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('data-toggle="tooltip"').tooltip();
                });

            </script>
            <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/mui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: please post your jsp

Comment: @redflar3 please f5 page to see my update

Comment: the same issue: ${pageContext.request.contextPath} don't return a project name

Comment: Is the page otherwise loading successfully or are you getting an exception? If you are getting an exception then please post it. And also post the rest of your controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using tiles the name of the page can be assigned directly from your tiles xml file
In order to do that you need to do the following

In your definition add another attribute called title

```
<definition name="index" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/main.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Index" />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/index.jsp" />
</definition>
```

In your template page (/WEB-INF/jsp/partical/main.jsp) insert the title attribute as below

```
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" /></title>
```

No attributes are needed from your controller so please delete this

```
mm.put("title", "Home");
```

If I can give you an opinion I believe you are not using the full potential apache tiles can offer.

Apache tiles is a framework that allow you to not replicate code in each page.
So it is important that you create a base layout for your website and then you can change for instance only the body in each page

To give you an example

**Template:**

```
<definition name="app.base" template="/WEB-INF/views/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Not Found" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jsp" />
        <put-list-attribute name="stylesheets_top">
            <add-attribute value="/resources/site/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/site/library/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css" /> 
        </put-list-attribute>   
        <put-list-attribute name="javascripts_bottom">
            <add-attribute value="/resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/site/library/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" />
        </put-list-attribute>   
</definition>
```

**Page that extends template:**

```
<definition name="home" extends="app.base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Home" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp" />
        <put-list-attribute name="stylesheets_top" inherit="true">
            <add-attribute value="/resources/site/home/home.css" />
        </put-list-attribute>   
        <put-list-attribute name="javascripts_bottom" inherit="true">
            <add-attribute value="/resources/site/home/home.js" />
        </put-list-attribute>   
</definition>
```

The page above will contain both the attributes of the parent page and the child page

The template might be as below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>


<tiles:importAttribute name="stylesheets_top" />
<tiles:importAttribute name="javascripts_bottom" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" /></title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- stylesheets top -->
        <c:forEach var="css" items="${stylesheets_top}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="${css}"/>">
        </c:forEach>
    </header>
    <div class="body">

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </footer>

</body>

<!-- scripts_bottom -->
<c:forEach var="script" items="${javascripts_bottom}">
    <script src="<c:url value="${script}"/>"></script>
</c:forEach>

</script>
</html>
```